# Rounding Column Footer in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In column 17 I have taken `total[1]` and divided it by `total[0]`.  The number is a long decimal. How would I shorten that decimal so that the value in column 17 to only have three decimal places (rounding to the nearest thousandths place if it has more than 3 decimals)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#battingtbl').DataTable({
    "searching": true,
    "pageLength": 40,
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    drawCallback: () => {
      const table = $('#battingtbl').DataTable();
      const tableData = table.rows({
        search: 'applied'
      }).data().toArray();
      const totals = tableData.reduce((total, rowData) => {
        total[0] += parseFloat(rowData[6]);
        total[1] += parseFloat(rowData[8]);
        return total;
      }, [0, 0]);
      $(table.column(6).footer()).text(totals[0]);
      $(table.column(8).footer()).text(totals[1]);
      $(table.column(17).footer()).text(totals[1] / totals[0]); // I WANT TO ROUND THIS
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: If you don't mind could you show me for my particular situation

Comment: The answer is in the linked duplicate; `toFixed(3)`

Comment: Like this? $(table.column(17).footer()).text(totals[1]/totals[0]).toFixed(3);

Comment: You need to call `toFixed()` on the result of the division operation which you place in the `text()` call: `$(table.column(17).footer()).text((totals[1]/totals[0]).toFixed(3));`

Comment: That did it. Thanks Rory

Comment: Oh. Is there any way to get rid of a zero if its before the decimal place? To make 0.500 become .500